# Can't get max quantity (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

**Circumstances:**

I created a product and added stock quantity: 80.
I installed Min/Max Quantities plugin and added min:1 & max: 20 for that product.
(Quantity varies from product to product)
**Problem:**

I need to echo max quantity of 20 on a shop page, but this code displays 80 which is stock quantity.

> echo $product->get_max_purchase_quantity();

Would you please let me know how to get the max quantity?

**functions.php:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'QTY');
function QTY()
{
    global $product;    
    ?>
        <div class="shopAddToCart">
        <button  value="-" class="minus"  >-</button>
        <input 
        type="text"
        disabled="disabled"
        autocomplete="off"
        size="2"
        value="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
        id="count"
        data-product-id= "<?php echo $product->get_id() ?>"
        data-in-cart="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['in_cart'] : 0;
    ?>"
        data-in-cart-qty="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
        class="quantity  qty"
        max_value = <?php echo $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(); ?>
        min_value = <?php echo $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(); ?>
        >
        
        <button type="button" value="+" class="plus"  >+</button>
        </div>
                              <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maximum_allowed_quantity` is stored in product meta so you can retrieve it by using the `get_post_meta` function. check below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'QTY');
function QTY(){
    global $product;
    if( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'maximum_allowed_quantity', true ) > 0 ){
        echo '<div>Max quantity: '.get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'maximum_allowed_quantity', true ).'</div>';
    }
}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhautik: Ohh, WoW, thank you a lot for your explanation and help. I've been struggling for days to solve this problem, but I couldn't. You are awesome, I've learnt a lot from you. Thank you again Bhautik : )